# CSS Grid, getting a scrollbar when I shouldn't be

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a [basic layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRYvp.jpg). I am trying to create the layout with CSS grid.

For some reason, I get the scrollbar when I shouldn't be as there is no content that is that tall to warrant a scrollbar.

I have created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/xxKoyMO).

**HTML**

```
<div class="l-grid">
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo"><span class="logo__brand-color">M</span>y Site</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="quote">
      <img
        src="https://www.viva.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Albert%20Einstein_0.jpg?itok=A5nVyyns"
        alt="celadet"
        class="quote__image"
      />
      <p class="quote__body">
        A hundred times every day I remind myself that my inner and outer life are based on the labors of other men, living and dead, and that I must exert myself in order to give in the same measure as I have received and am still receiving.
      </p>
      <h3 class="quote__author">Albert Einstein</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="search__field"
        placeholder="Search quotes"
      />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="footer-nav">
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">&middot;</li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">Help</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">&middot;</li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  font-size: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #292c37;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Satisfy", cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.logo__brand-color {
  color: hsl(355, 78%, 39%, 80%);
}

.quote {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.quote__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%, 60%);
  border-style: inset;
}

.quote__body {
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 85%);
  line-height: 1.93em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.quote__author {
  color: hsl(355, 78%, 39%, 80%);
  grid-column: span 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.search {
  background-color: #363a49;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search__field {
  background-color: #292c37;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 60%);
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.footer-nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-nav__item,
.footer-nav__link {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-nav__link {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.footer-nav__item--separator {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1;` is invalid! - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Comment: Good catch @Paulie_D, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this.

But i think the culprit behind all this is the css being applied to :

```
<li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">·</li>
```

Which is

```
.footer-nav__item--separator {
   font-size: 3em;
   line-height: 0.5em;
}
```

Default font size : `16px`

Now to know how much height our text is going to require we multiply the `font-size` by the `line-height` (em,rem,px or any other unit doesn't matter on the line height)

```
3em * 16px = 48px // Size of the character 
48px * .5 = 24px  // The height of the text
```

As you can see the character is much more bigger than the height, so it will spill out and cause a scrollbar to appear.

Solutions:

1. Give the footer more height
2. Adjust the `line-height` or the `font-size`
3. If it's just one page, just hide the overflow seems like the easiest solution

Comment: hmm am I doing this right in terms of separating the links with `&middot;`? I do want a circle/dot separating the links, but is `&middot;` the way to do it?

Comment: By the way, you're 100% right, that was the cause because when I comment out the two separator dots `<li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">&middot;</li>` it all behaves as it should, I no longer get the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `grid-template-rows: auto;` css to remove the scroll bar.

```
.l-grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

It may help you!

Answer (score -1):

You can do that like this:
Remove height from .l-grid css or add height:auto

```css
   

.l-grid {
      display: grid;
      width: 1100px;
      height:auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      grid-template-columns: 1;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
      align-items: center;
 }
```